# How to obtain the statistical significance of a given community structure for a directed network?

Tags: statistical-significance, clustering, networks

So, I have several directed (multi-edged) networks, and within them each node has been assigned to one of seven categories (based on some *a priori* circumstances). Each category *should* have a higher within-category interaction rate, but I want to test the statistical significance of this.

Since "a set of nodes, densely connected internally" is pretty much the definition of a community, I want to manually impose my community assignments on the nodes in the network and then test whether this assignment is statistically more "community-like" than a random assignment. **In essence, my question is: "Is this given community structure statistically significant?"**

I found [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.81.046110) which seems to have a way of measuring the statistical significance of a single community group in the network, but it doesn't seem to apply to a given, entire community structure. I also found [this baby](http://snap.stanford.edu/networks2013/papers/netnips2013_submission_7.pdf), but it seems to only be focused on much smaller, local structures.

There's gotta be a way to do this for directed, multi-edged networks, I just can't seem to find any! (Additionally, I'll have to do this analysis in R, so mega-triple-extra bonus points if you know of an R package that already does this.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the subject of this gem by Peel, Larremore and Clauset: [The ground truth about metadata and community detection](http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/3/5/e1602548).  See the section where they introduce the blockmodel entropy significance test.  I dont know of an implementation in R, but Leto's original implementation is in matlab on his [Github](https://github.com/piratepeel/neoSBM).

Comment: It seems that the significance test [BESTest](https://github.com/dblarremore/BESTest) takes an "NxN *undirected* network adjacency matrix. Code will check to ensure that the matrix is either symmetric or triangular."  This is still better than any other leads I have, but it looks like I'd have to lose the directed aspect of my networks.

Comment: Ok, sorry I missed that.  Its probably possible to generalize their method to directed stochastic block models.  I'll mess around with it over the next few days to see.